# self-avoiding random walk and no turning back in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random

There is a two-dimensional array, 8X8
   cube =

```
-1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
-1   **2** **2** **2** **2** **2** **2**  -1
-1   **2**   2     2     2     2   **2**  -1
-1   **2**   2     2     2     2   **2**  -1
-1   **2**   2     2     2     2   **2**  -1
-1   **2**   2     2     2     2   **2**  -1
-1   **2** **2** **2** **2** **2** **2**  -1
-1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
```

For this array, a particle could move in the lattice, It starts from one 
side to the other side. Choose a site randomly from the outermost layer of value 2, as the starting point of particle moving. The particle then moves forward, it can turn left or right or go ahead, but no turning back, we can determine the moving direction by a random number. When the next site is -1, the particle stops moving.  When the first moving route finishes, choose another site randomly from the outermost layer of value 2, do the same operation.

How to realize above-mentioned algorithm in MATLAB. The difficulty of programming is that the particle couldn’t turn back, which is difficult for coding.

[image]

```
One possible result, start direction B and C
```

[enter link description here](http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XMjk4ODU4OTY4.html?f=6176340)

```
self-avoiding random walk, and I need no turning back
```

Comment: Your question would benefit from some code to start from.

Comment: Simply make each node inaccessible when you move onto it. Your question definitely needs some clarification, like what the `-1` and `2` values represent and how they relate to the 4 different colored squares in your example image. And enough of your code to show us how you're currently choosing the path.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, -1 represents external environment, 2  represents porous medium. Gas molecules can diffuse through one side to the other side.

Comment: @Kongling That really doesn't tell me anything from a graph perspective, unfortunately. Where can I walk and where can't I walk? What is the desired path?

Comment: Sorry, the graph is not consistent with my question, the graph is more complicated. Choose a site randomly from the outermost layer of value 2, as the starting point of particle moving, the particle then moves forward, when the next site is -1, the walk stops.

Comment: As I said originally, make the node inaccessible when you move onto it. Each time you move onto a node with a value of `2`, make it `0` and select your next move only from non-zero adjacent nodes.

Comment: Ok, I will have a try, thank you for your advice again.